# Strange Issue when using pywin32 with zmq

Tags: python, pywin32, pyzmq

Description:
I want to seal python to Windows service. Then I use pywin32.
My python scripts will use *pyzmq*.

Everytime when I want to start the service, the service will be stopped after starting a few seconds. I try using `try catch` to catch the exception in python code. It's useless. Then I try use python debug command, I found the *pywin32* will be crashed. I checked the event log in windows as below. Seems the zmq version has some problems. I try uninstalling and installing *pyzmq*. The issue is still existing.

Does any one can help with this?

Here is :

> Faulting application name: pythonservice.exe, version: 2.7.224.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5badbe1d Faulting module name: libzmq.pyd, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x5b6d9b30 Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset:
>   0x0000000000059877 Faulting process id: 0x2080 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d4b9fe6fefc040 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe Faulting module
>   path: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\libzmq.pyd Report Id:
>   c46e9138-25f1-11e9-813b-0050569a1750 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: I think you need to post your Python code. We can't possibly suggest what might be wrong with it otherwise.